list all stripe subscriptions as per price id
Can any body tell how to filter out Subscription from a particular price id OR from a particular product? This question has been asked using node.js but is there a way to view this on the stripe dashboard directly?

Looks like there's a filter in the dashboard that let's you filter subscriptions using price IDs: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/subscriptions

